# How to Fetch Media Link Using ChromeDriver with Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to fetch media link for a video URL in Chrome `DevTools -> Network -> Media`, while running with `Selenium` and `ChromeDriver`, in order to automate certain file downloads.
Any ideas whether it is feasible at all, if so how to fetch with the script.
I appreciate any inputs. Thanks in advance.

Sample DevTools Window Media Link:
[image: Sample DevTools Window Media Link]

Comment: Is the media link somewhere on the HTML page you are loading to let it be scraped?

Comment: No Matthew, it is hidden somehow via player they use, may be thru encryption.
But direct mp4 (or some other formatted video) file link can be seen in devTools Media section, once video starts playing in chrome.